# Why is my right click/start menu behind my application?

Tags: windows

My menu appears behind my window? any solutions?

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubZS2.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm00p.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen with every application or just some? If your window is "Always On Top" then right clicks on apps behind it will not render correctly in some situations.